# How to unmarshall JSON in golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have trouble unmarshal access the values of a JSON string in my golang service.

I read the documentation for golang but the JSON objects in the examples are all differently formated.

from my api i get the following JSON string:

```
{"NewDepartment":
    {
    "newDepName":"Testabt",
    "newDepCompany":2,
    "newDepMail":"Bla@bla.org"
    }
}
```

in go I defined the following data types:

```golang
type NewDepartment struct {
    NewDepName string `json:"newDepName"`
    NewDepCompany   int `json:"newDepCompany"`
    NewDepMail string `json:"newDepMail"`
}

type NewDeps struct {
    NewDeps   []NewDepartment `json:"NewDepartment"`
}
```

I try to unmarshal the JSON (from request Body) and access the values, but I can't get any results

```golang
var data types.NewDepartment
    errDec := json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &data)

fmt.Println("AddDepartment JSON string got: " + data.NewDepName)
```

but it contains no string - nothing is displayed but no error on unmarshaling or Println.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `NewDepartment` in the json is an object, not an array. So similarly the `NewDeps` field in your Go code should be a struct, not a slice. That is, change `NewDeps []NewDepartment` to `NewDeps NewDepartment`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

First update is to make `NewDeps.NewDeps` a single object, not an array (according to the provided JSON).

The second update is to deserialize JSON into `NewDeps`, not into `NewDepartment`.

Working code:

```golang
type NewDepartment struct {
    NewDepName string      `json:"newDepName"`
    NewDepCompany int      `json:"newDepCompany"`
    NewDepMail string      `json:"newDepMail"`
}

type NewDeps struct {
    NewDeps NewDepartment  `json:"NewDepartment"`
}

func main() {
    var data NewDeps
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &data)

    fmt.Println("AddDepartment JSON string got: " + data.NewDeps.NewDepName)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Sn02hwETRv1